# Flyout alternative Windows Phone 8.0

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, flyout

I'm doing a WP 8.0 compatible app, into that I need to put on a specific page a flyout menu.
Now, the Flyout element is only compatible with WP 8.1, so now I'm asking if there's an alternative compatible with WP8.

Specifically, I want a button which, after the user's Tap, shows off others elements that drop down under the button.

Maybe there's a solution that can be easily found online, but I'm italian and I really don't know how it's called that kind of menu in English.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Silverlight for Phone, there's the Phone Toolkit (http://phone.codexplex.com or via Nuget) that provides the ContextMenuService.

The base variant only supports Menu-Items in the ContextMenu, but as it is open source, you can extend it to show any Xaml content.

Comment: I've already seen that kind of menu but it didn't satisfy my needs. But if there's not any real alternative to Flyouts I guess that I might use that instead.
thank you.